# Кроссбраузерные проблемы с dots

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть [сайт](http://mytrueblog.site/place_relax/main.php)

на движке хрома выгдят вот так[image: вот так]

а на движке moz вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я их только не крутил эти dots не получается сделать их одинаковыми на двух этих движках

Пробовал это

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.feedback-dots li button').height(auto);
    }).resize();
});
```

Последнее что стояло в css

```
button
      max-width: 18px !important
      /* min-height: 18px */
      height: 100%
      border-radius: 50%
      background-color: #fff
      border: 3px solid #000 !important
      font-size: 0
```

Comment: img во flex контейнере обязательно нужно оборачиватьв оболочку div > img. Иначе будет растягиваться без учета пропорции. https://prnt.sc/qemvn9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было для элемента `.feedback li button` задать `height 18px, width 18px and padding 0`, все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы позиционируете футер отзыва используя `flexbox`, то укажите для `button` свойство `flex-shrink: 0;`

Подробнее про `flexbox` на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: к сожалению не сработало, элементы по прожнему растягиваются и не однородны на разных браузерах.